# Make sure MySQL processes close after running

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site running in PHP and MySQL, recently it has started to not respond and not load pages. My Web host says it because of open processes:

```
Id  User    Host    db  Command Time    State   Info
28312497    eximstats   localhost   eximstats   Sleep   0    NULL   
42808356    integra_integra 82.152.148.162:63299    integra_integra Sleep   3177     NULL
42808809    integra_integra 82.152.148.162:63302    integra_integra Sleep   3057     NULL
42813450    integra_integra 82.152.148.162:63308    integra_integra Sleep   2714     NULL
42824809    integra_integra 82.152.148.162:63313    integra_integra Sleep   2605     NULL
```

How can i make sure the processes do not stay open?

my queries look like:

```
$sql="SELECT * From table where... ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
```

then either:

```
$result=mysql_fetch_array($rs);
```

or

```
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
echo data here...
}
```

Comment: As long as the script ends (and you don't do something very odd or use persistent connections) the connection should close.

Comment: its not closing though as I'm getting the above logs/errors. my scripts are just things like SELECT * from / INSERT into ... etc

Comment: How do you create the connection? Do your script run then exit or does it keep going forever?

Comment: mysql{*}_close(), if you are using mysql library

Comment: im not sure.. see my edit in a minute

Comment: I would start with changing to PDO or mysqli instead of the deprecated mysql_* functions, cause they are generally bad to use. I dont think they should lock the database like you describe, but still worth doing. After that, check so that the script exits, that it reaches the end, if it does, the connection should be released by itself, but might be worth to close it at the end just to be safe.

Comment: i don't have time to change my whole site to PDO or mysqli - I'm happy with how it is at the moment!